# A limit of quotient of sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_nb_n }=0$. Is it true that: $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}{{\sum_{n=1}^{k}{a_n}}\over{\sum_{n=1}^{k}{a_nb_n }}}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}{1\over b_k}$$
I have seen similar statements to hold using Stolz-Cesaro, but that would need the strict requirement that one of these partial sums be monotone. I should also say that nothing particular of $a_n$ or $b_n$ is given, so that each of the series may not necessarily converge to $0$ absolutely.

Comment: It's false. Just take $a_n=0$, $b_n=1$. The quotient in limit in the LHS isn't even defined, while RHS is $1$.

Comment: Moreover, take $b_n = 2+(-1)^n$ to find an example where the right-hand side isn't defined, but the left-hand side will equal $\frac12$ for many nice sequences $\{a_n\}$. In general, there's no reason to expect that this should be true when it isn't close to true even for finite sums.

Comment: I think it would be interesting to see if with the stronger hypothesis of both limits existing, whether they are necessarily equal.

Comment: @jjagmath I agree, in my particular case I am considering sequences that are nonzero everywhere, and assuming the limits do exist.

Comment: @AndrewSotomayor Then you should state that in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: @jjagmath I just created a new question with a stronger hypothesis [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396327/limit-of-quotient-of-partial-sums).

Comment: @AndrewSotomayor In the new question you weakened the hypothesis.