# Limit of Quotient of partial sums

Tags: limits, derivatives

Let $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ be continuous, differentiable (non-constant) functions such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{a(x)}=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{a(x)b(x)}=0$, with $b(x)$ nondecreasing, such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{1\over b(x)} $ exists. I am trying to show that: $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{k}{a(n)}\over{\sum_{n=1}^{k}{a(n)b(n)}}}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}{1\over b(k)}$$So far I have managed to extend the sums to continuous functions in order to apply L'Hospital's rule, but the functions are not actually differentiable everywhere, but only at non-integers (derivatives have no infinite discontinuities), so I am not sure if it can even be done. I know that the sums can be approximated by integrals, but this would remove the $0/0$ condition, and L'Hosptial's rule will not apply.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you should strengthen the assumption on $a(x)$ to being not eventually constant, since $a(2)=a(3)=\cdots=0$ is currently possible and will break the desired equality.

Comment: The statement is false more generally: take $a(n) = 3^{-n}$ and $b(n)=1-2^{-n}$ for example. If you assume that $a(n)>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$ diverges, then I believe the statement can be proved by a standard epsilon-$N$ argument.

Comment: @GregMartin good point, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I will edit the question soon, but the limit of the quotient of sums is assumed to be of $0/0$ indeterminate form.

Comment: Please look for further counterexamples before editing that into the question: the result seems very unlikely to me, precisely because converging to $0$ can be achieved by arbitrarily changing one of the early terms—it's not a fundamental property of a special category of infinite series.